# How to Import Module Into Polymer 3 Starter Kit

Tags: node.js, import, es6-modules, polymer-3.x

I am trying to import a random number generator into the Polymer 3 Starter Kit.  I have read through (https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/es6), but am still struggling to get a test project working.

To initialize the project I took the following steps

1. `mkdir polymer-3-kit`
2. `polymer init` (selected starter kit)
3. `npm i --save @polymer/paper-button`
4. `npm i random-number`

I would like to press a button and show a new random number each time to button is pressed.  My code is as follows:

```
import {PolymerElement, html} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@polymer/paper-button/paper-button.js';
import {generator as rn} from '../node_modules/random-number/index.js'

  class MyView1 extends PolymerElement {
    static get properties() {
      num: Number
    }
    static get template() {
      return html `
        <div class="card">
          <h1>View One</h1>
          <p>${num}</p>
          <paper-button on-tap="updateNumber">Do Something</paper-button>
        </div>
      `;
    }

    updateNumber() {
      let num = rn()
      console.log('A random number has been generated')
    }

}

window.customElements.define('my-view1', MyView1);
```

Running this code generates the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/random-number/index.js' does not provide an export named 'random'

The random generator code is like:

```
void function(root){
  function random() {
    // code
  }
  function generator() {
    // generator
  }
  function defaults() {
    // defaults
  }
  module.exports.random = random
  module.exports.generator = generator
  module.exports.defaults = defaults
}(this)
```

**How do I correctly import this module and update the DOM with a random number on a button press?**